# Google Play Services - Room - CreatorID Not Unique

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Is it just me or is the [getCreatorId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/Room.html#getCreatorId%28%29) method in Room not unique for automatch games?

I have some logic in my game that is based on a unique entity deciding things, such as which player belongs on which team. Each client waits to receive this information from the 'host' (which is the room creator in this case) before launching into and setting up the game.

```
@Override
public void onRoomConnected(int status, Room room) {
  // Game Lobby is full
  if (status != GamesClient.STATUS_OK) {
    return;
  }

  this.room = room;

  // Assign the players teams
  if (room.getParticipantId(activity.gameHelperManager.gameHelper.getGamesClient().getCurrentPlayerId()).equals(room.getCreatorId())) {
  // Some logic here
  activity.androidManager.sendMessage(Data Sent Here);

  activity.game.startGame(GameType.MULTIPLAYER);
  }
}
```

On the other side of things:

```
@Override
public void onRealTimeMessageReceived(RealTimeMessage message) {

  // Get Message from host about game specific properties is here
  if (data.contains(Message Tag Here)) {
    // Parse information
    activity.game.startGame(GameType.MULTIPLAYER);
  }
}
```

However, each client views itself as the host in the [onRoomConnected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomUpdateListener.html#onRoomConnected) method during an auto-match type game.

Is there a solution to this or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: I have found the answer, it looks like it is an 'api' bug or misunderstanding to say the least, see [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/issues/4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admittedly, our documentation is a bit misleading (I'm requesting a fix right away), but here's the explanation of what went through our heads when we designed this :-D

What automatching really does is connect different rooms created by different people, and making them into virtually one room with everybody in it. So different people in the room may have a different idea of who was the room's creator. So using the room's creator as a way to decide who goes first is generally not a good idea.

Using the participant ID directly isn't a good idea either (because someone with a lexicographically very high participant ID would find themselves going last on every single game they play).

Please see my answer to the following question for more ideas on how to decide who goes first:

[How to decide who is the first player when user plays quick game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087389/how-to-decide-who-is-the-first-player-when-user-plays-quick-game/19090021#19090021)

Comment: Thanks Bruno, this information is very insightful (especially regarding participant ID's not being truly 'randomized'). In my case, it didn't matter who made the decisions, as long as it was agreed upon by participants as to who would be the one making these decisions (no advantage is gained, such as going first for example).  However your number 2 suggestion is something I will remember should it matter in the future.

Comment: So... there is basically no virtual merged room id availible to us? I need some string, number, whatever that will be the same for all players in the game as I need to use it for seed to Random() some things same way for every player in the game. Been using that while using invite, automatching ruined it all :/