# Google play games services multiplayer support displaying same data on both device

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-play-services

I am developing an android real time multiplayer quiz game. For multiplayer support i have used Google play games service. I am following the Button Clickers 2000 tutorial.I have retrieved the Questions and answers via Asynctask from the online server. Now when multiplayer game starts both players get different questions. But in real time i need to show the same questions to both players when they select multiplayer option.How can i achieve this? any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with programming, its general about tutorials, references.

Comment: I just need to how can i define a host participant who will create quiz-questions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try different options such as sorting participants ID then alphabetically selects the first one and select it as a host who will create quiz questions. You can also look at [1]: [How to decide who is the first player when user plays quick game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087389/how-to-decide-who-is-the-first-player-when-user-plays-quick-game/19090021#19090021)